# Не работает связь с клавиатурой WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Вот такой код калькулятора на WPF.

Пример метода для кнопки (btn 1)

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    KeyAll(1);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------    

void KeyAll(int enter)
{

    if (operation == "")
    {
        number1 = (number1 * 10) + enter;
        txtDisplay.Text = number1.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        number2 = (number2 * 10) + enter;
        txtDisplay.Text = number2.ToString();
    }

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------

private void Grid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Key)
    {
        case Key.NumPad1:
            KeyAll(1);
            break; //и так далее
```

Пробовал через (KeyDown через PreviewKeyDown) Пробовал подписаться на событие как к кнопке так и на уровне Grid.
Кликаю мышкой — работает. Нажимаю на клавиатуру — работает, но только если перед этим нажать на любую цифру мышкой.

Comment: Возможно фокус не на том гриде, поэтому не срабатывает. Обрабатывайте нажатия клавиш в событиях окна, а не грида.

Comment: @ Андрей NOP Вы имеете ввиду здесь `<Button x:Name="btn1" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="30" Click="btn1_Click"   >1</Button>` или на уровне `<Grid.ColumnDefinitions> <ColumnDefinition/>` Во общем то и там и там пробовал. Фокус на txtDisply я так понимаю , а как его на кнопку 1 к примеру перенести не пойму.
`

Comment: Я имею ввиду подписаться не на `Grid.PreviewKeyDown`, а на `Window.PreviewKeyDown`

Comment: @Андрей NOP Спасибо, всё работает!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего ваш `Grid` не имеет фокуса во время нажатия клавиши, а при клике мышью по кнопке вы ставите фокус и всё начинает работать как надо.

Решение — обрабатывать события нажатия клавиш у самого корневого элемента — у окна. Т.е. подпишитесь не на `Grid.PreviewKeyDown`, а на `Window.PreviewKeyDown`